# Regex for Ronin wallet address

Tags: swift, regex

I created a regex to identify the following string example:

`ronin:50460c4cd74094cd591f454cad457e99c4ab8bf1`

The regex doesn't recognize it. This is it:

```
let roninWalletPattern = #"ronin:[a-fA-F0-9]{46}"#

// Checks regex
let result = walletAddress.range(
        of: roninWalletPattern,
        options: .regularExpression
)
let validAddress = (result != nil)
```

so if it's nil is not valid.

What am I missing on that regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 40 characters after the `ronin:` part, not 46. The `{46}` only applies to the previous token, which is `[a-fA-F0-9]`.

Change `{46}` to `{40}`.